# Dynamic height for TextEditor

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to fit the `TextEditor` inside a `ScrollView`.

Is there a way to make `TextEditor` only takes up the space that it needs to fit all  text?

or simply, how to change the `height` of the `TextEditor` dynamically to fit all the text?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

##### iOS 13

You can use an invisible `Text` in a `ZStack` to make it dynamic.

```
ZStack {
    TextEditor(text: $text)
    Text(text).opacity(0).padding(.all, 8) // <- This will solve the issue if it is in the same ZStack
}
```

<sub>Note that you should consider changing font size and other properties to match the `TextEditor`</sub>

<sub>Here I used it in a list for demo:</sub>

[image: Preview]

---

##### iOS 16

If you are just looking for a vertical growing input field, there is a parameter called `axis` in `TextField` that causes the field to grow vertically if needed:

```
TextField("", text: $text, axis: .vertical)
```

<sub>Note that if you test with the mac keyboard, you need to hold <kbd>option</kbd> for new lines.</sub>

---

Comment: Oh yes. It worked. Thanks Mojtaba. 
But I faced some more issues. So I decided to use UITextView for now.

Answer (score 4):

using

```
TextEditor(text: someTextBinding)
   .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

does the job for me (== height is dynamic, width is static)

Answer (score 2):

Dynamic height can also be achieved with combination use of `Text` and `overlay()` with `TextEditor`.

```
Text(textVal.isEmpty ? "Your placeholder" : textVal)
    .font(.body)
    .padding(.vertical, 8)
    .padding(.horizontal, 18)
    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
    .opacity(textVal.isEmpty ? 1 : 0)
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, minHeight: 40, alignment: .leading)
    .background(
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
            .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.2), lineWidth: 1)
            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
    )
    .overlay(
        TextEditor(text: $textVal)
            .font(.body)
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
            .padding(.horizontal, 15)
    )
```

For transparent background of `TextEditor` add below code on View init:

```
init(yourProperty: String) {
    self.yourProperty = yourProperty
    UITextView.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

Answer (score -2):

there's a nice answer, built in function

https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-make-a-textfield-expand-vertically-as-the-user-types

```
TextField(placeholder, text: $value, axis: .vertical)
        .textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
```